# removing android: prefix for every attribute

Tags: android, xml

Android layout xml file has "android:" prefix with every attribute.

is there any solution for removing them.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content">
  <Button android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:text="@string/test_button">
  </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: But why do you want to remove that?

Comment: increases manually modification time. Up to me it is not a develloper friendly approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be this post helps you; http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/d94c1f53a331c53b

Please see this post to know, why there is an android prefix; [Android XML layout files and namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404560/android-xml-layout-files-and-namespace)

**Update:** (After Josh's comment)

Another way to do the same is to use a regular expression in Eclipse's Find/Replace tool. This method is easier than the first one.

Comment: Whoa, that script you linked to is WAY more complicated than doing a regex find/replace in Eclipse :(

Comment: @Josh: My answer is not wrong as you downvoted it but still I updated it. Thanks.